# C# property delegation to objects

Tags: class, properties, delegates

In my WPF-application I use many propertys for binding.
All the properties are often only return the value of a special XNode.

Therefore I wrote a method, which gets and sets the value of the node.

For example:

```
public int Radius
    {
        get
        {
            return GetNodeValue<int>("Radius");
        }
        set
        {
            SetNodeValue("Radius", value);
        }
    }
```

Because I've many of this properties, which always have the same code, it would be nice if I can do it in a shorter way.

I thought of using a special class which will do the code:

```
    public class CNodeProperty
    {
        public CNodeProperty(string name)
        {
            _Name = Name;
        }
        public static implicit operator int(CNodeProperty d)
        {
            return GetNodeValue<int>(_Name);
        }

        private string _Name;
    }

    public int Radius { get; set; } = new CNodeProperty("Radius");
```

This would help me avoiding to type always the same Code.
The Problem: Using this way, I can only access static variables. But inside the `GetNodeValue` I also have to access local variables of the class which has the property (which I may also give to the constructor of `CNodeProperty`, but this isn't possible).

Any ideas how I can delegate the property get and set to a separate class?